# Gson.fromJson() not working as expected

Tags: android, json, gson, jsonreader

I've a huge json string that I want to use to retrieve objects.
That's why I used Gson instead of the usual JsonObject as said [here](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/streaming).

Here is my code:

```
public List<ProductJavaBean> getProductsData()
{
    url = "http://api.xxx/products.json";
    String line = "";
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    List<ProductJavaBean> products = new ArrayList<ProductJavaBean>();

    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
        URI website = new URI(url);

        request.setURI(website);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);

        JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(),"UTF-8"));
        reader.beginArray();    

        while(reader.hasNext())
        {
            ProductJavaBean product = gson.fromJson(reader ,ProductJavaBean.class);
            products.add(product);
        }
        reader.endArray();
        reader.close();
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        Log.e("Error retrieving products data:" , exc.getMessage());
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }
    return products;
}
```

as [I followed the API samples](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/streaming).

But I have a strange behaviour on the fromJson method:

> The method fromJson(String, Class) in the type Gson is not
>   applicable for the arguments (JsonReader, Class)

[image]

Thanks.

EDIT:

here are my imports:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.R;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.JsonReader;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.gz.constancl.model.ProductJavaBean;
```

Comment: Would you mind showing us your imports?!

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17453406/gson-with-mixed-read

Comment: Just updated my post

Comment: Yes it was a duplicate ... sorry about that, closing the topic ....

Answer (score -1):

You can modify ur code from

```
JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(),"UTF-8"));
reader.beginArray();    

while(reader.hasNext())
{
    ProductJavaBean product = gson.fromJson(reader ,ProductJavaBean.class);
    products.add(product);
}
reader.endArray();
reader.close();
```

to

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<ProductJavaBean>>() {}.getType();
products  = new Gson().fromJson(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()), listType);
```

Comment: There's no need to modify the code. The import `android.util.JsonReader`was just wrong and needed to be changed to `com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader`. That's also why this question was flagged as a duplicate.